# Difference between mobx's `action.bound` and arrow functions on class functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, mobx

Using arrow functions on a class with babel transpiles it so the definition is bound in the constructor. And so it is not in the prototype and it is not available via `super` when inheriting. It is also not as efficient when scaling by creating many instances.

There are more blog posts on this topic, but I just wanted to know the difference in how mobx.action.bound is handled compared to arrow functions when using babel.

Comparing the two:

```
class Example {
   test = () => {
      console.log(this.message)
   }
}

class Example {
   @action.bound
   test() {
      console.log(this.message)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are 2 variables `@action` and `@action.bound` have an effect on:

1. **Binding**: How `this` is bound in the resulting function.
2. **Prototype**: If the resulting function is in the prototype.

To summarize, these are the rules:

- `@action` preserves the original function's binding and prototype-inclusion. If the original function is not bound, the result will not be, and vise versa. And if the original function is not in the prototype, the result will not be, and vise versa.
- `@action.bound` will always result in a function which is bound, and which is in the prototype.

## How Binding is affected:

You can easily test this like so:

```
class Store {
  unbound() {
    console.log('unbound', this)
  }

  arrow = () => {
    console.log('arrow', this)
  }
}
const storeInstance = new Store()
const unbound = storeInstance.unbound
const arrow = storeInstance.arrow
unbound()
arrow()
// console displays:
// unbound undefined
// arrow Store
```

Now let's try adding `@action`:

```
class Store {
  @action
  unbound() {
    console.log('unbound', this)
  }

  @action
  arrow = () => {
    console.log('arrow', this)
  }
}
const storeInstance = new Store()
const unbound = storeInstance.unbound
const arrow = storeInstance.arrow
unbound()
arrow()
// console still displays:
// unbound undefined
// arrow Store
```

Now let's try adding `@action.bound`:

```
class Store {
  @action.bound
  unbound() {
    console.log('unbound', this)
  }

  @action.bound
  arrow = () => {
    console.log('arrow', this)
  }
}
const storeInstance = new Store()
const unbound = storeInstance.unbound
const arrow = storeInstance.arrow
unbound()
arrow()
// console now displays:
// unbound Store
// arrow Store
```

As you can see, `@action` maintains the function's bindings (or lack of binding). Meanwhile, `@action.bound` will always return a bound function, thus turning an unbound function into a bound one, and an already bound function will remain bounded.

## How prototype is affected:

As for your concern about inheritance, here is the `Store` definition:

```
class Store {
  unbound() {}
  arrow = () => {}
  @action unboundAction() {}
  @action.bound unboundActionBound() {}
  @action arrowAction = () => {}      
  @action.bound arrowActionBound = () => {}
}
```

And this is what the storeInstance looks like:
[image]

As you pointed out, `arrow = () => {}` is not part of the prototype. And to answer your question, `@action arrow = () => {}` will not result in a function which is in the prototype. It looks like `@action` preserves the previous behavior. However, `@action.bound` will always result in a function which is in the prototype.